# Color Detection of Balls using Webcams and perform actions

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, color-detection

I have a clear idea how to identify colors of any objects placed in front of webcam but i need some help for performing some actions according to the color.
Suppose for a red ball,my laptop screen will slide to next image of any image slider and for a blue ball it will slide to the previous.
Any helps or suggestions please.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Did a lot of google but nothing found useful..If you can tell me something relatable so i can search for it specifically